# Семантика HTML5: тег для логотипа img

Tags: html5

```
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1><a href=/>АЛТАЮ 75 ЛЕТ</a></h1>
        <h2>И НАМ ЕСТЬ ЧТО СКАЗАТЬ</h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>
```

Я хочу вставить логотип в шапку, но не в теге hgroup, какой тег для логотипа img лучше использовать?

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл использовать не тег `img`, а [image replacement](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно сказал [[@drdaeman](/users/2694/drdaeman)](/users/2694/drdaeman) лучше использовать background-image в CSS например так:

```
<header id="header">
    <hgroup>
        <h1><a href=/>АЛТАЮ 75 ЛЕТ</a></h1>
        <h2>И НАМ ЕСТЬ ЧТО СКАЗАТЬ</h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>
<style>
#header{
 background-image: url(logo.gif);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Напрашивается вопрос. Чем этот способ лучше обычного <img/>? Прокомментируйте, будьте так любезны.

Comment: Это не лучше (я такого не говорил! и поэтому же не отправил комментарий, а не ответ) и не хуже, это просто имеет другую семантику. HTML-документ определяет структуру, а CSS — представление. Дальше зависит от того, *семантически* нужна ли картинка в шапке, или она там нужна только визуально. А это уже на взгляд разработчика и дизайнера.

Скажем, в случае буквицы или фигурного заголовка, картинка однозначно неуместна. А вот в случае логотипа — я, лично, теряюсь. Можно сказать по всякому. Если картинка — то же самое «Алтаю 75 лет», то картинка не нужна. Если нет — не знаю, думать надо.